Получение текущего пользователя в Power BI
Требуется получить текущего пользователя и прокинуть его в качестве параметра в хранимую процедуру.
Нашел статью, что можно получить через метод DAX = USERNAME(), но как передать в процедуру пока не нашел и вообще насколько это возможно?
попытался сделать такой запрос = Sql.Database("","",[Query="EXEC getName @par = " & USERNAME()]), но видимо надо как-то прописать чтобы функция DAX читалась.
Подскажите реализуем ли такой таск или есть обходное решение?
Способ RLS не подходит, так как в процедуре зашита рекурсивная логика, которая зависит от текущего пользователя
